# É possível saber quais são as shapes atualmente disponíveis?

Tags: python-3.x

Estou a usar a modulo `turtle` de *Python* e gostaria de saber se tem uma maneira de saber quais são os tipos de **shape** que a `turtle` pode assumir. Eu sei que pode-se criar ou adicionar mais shapes ao dicionário do `TurtleScreen`, mas sinceramente não tive tempo para ler toda a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/turtle.html)e não sei bem do que ela estava a falar nesse momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme [a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/turtle.html#turtle.shape) (ênfase minha):

> `turtle.shape(name=None)`
>
> Parâmetros:    `name` – uma string que é um nome válido de forma
>
> Faz com que a forma da tartaruga seja aquela com o nome dado ou, se o nome não foi dado, retorna o nome da forma atual. Uma forma com o nome `name` precisa existir no dicionário de formas da `TurtleScreen`. **Inicialmente existem as seguintes formas poligonais: “`arrow`”, “`turtle`”, “`circle`”, “`square`”, “`triangle`”, “`classic`”**. Para aprender sobre como lidar com formas veja o método de `Screen` [`register_shape()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/turtle.html#turtle.register_shape).

**Atualização:** para obter uma lista de nomes das formas suportadas - tanto as padronizadas quanto as adicionadas pelo programador - de forma dinâmica, você pode usar o método [`getshapes`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/turtle.html#turtle.getshapes) de `TurtleScreen`:

```
>>> Screen().getshapes()
['arrow', 'blank', 'circle', 'classic', 'square', 'triangle', 'turtle']
```

Nota: não sei se essa é a melhor maneira de se obter uma instância de `TurtleScreen`, pois sou iniciante nessa biblioteca.

Comment: @cell É porque eu sou o autor da postagem (resposta) e portanto sou automaticamente notificado de qualquer comentário nela - seja ele dirigido a mim ou não. Da mesma forma, eu não consigo te "tagar" na pergunta, porque você é autor dela.